# How to select first N elements in hierarchical query (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following problem. There is an hirarchy with millions of elements in oracle12 db. How can I select first N objects of hierarchy. It doesn't matter which objects should be selected, the only requirement is that objects should be in heirarcy.  Rownum filter doesn't work at all:

```
SELECT object_id
FROM objects
WHERE rownum < 10
START WITH object_id = 9072243521013844211
CONNECT BY PRIOR object_id = parent_id
```

I get the following execution plan: filtering is done after objects select.

```
/*
LEVEL   PLAN    ROWS    COST    PREDICATES
*/
1   SELECT STATEMENT (OPTIMIZER=ALL_ROWS)   8   1   

2     COUNT         

3       FILTER          filter(ROWNUM<10)

4         CONNECT BY (WITH FILTERING)           access("PARENT_ID"=PRIOR "OBJECT_ID")

5           TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID) "OBJECTS"         

6             INDEX (UNIQUE SCAN) "XPKOBJECTS"  1   1   access("OBJECT_ID"=9072243521013844211)

5           NESTED LOOPS            

6             CONNECT BY PUMP           

6             TABLE ACCESS (BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED) "OBJECTS"   8   1   

7               INDEX (RANGE SCAN) "XIF25OBJECTS"   8   1   access("PARENT_ID"=PRIOR "OBJECT_ID")
```

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by *'first n objects'*? Also, it would be helpful if you gave some sample data and the desired outcome... By the way -  have you tried using `level` ?

Comment: Which version of Oracle are you on? If you are on 12, you can use fetch/offset, but I'll wait to give an example until I hear back

Comment: The question is unclear. What do you mean by "the only requirement is that objects should be in heirarcy"? Sharing the table description with some example data would also help.

Answer (score 0):

The following example solution should provide some guidance:

```
with objects as 
(select level object_id, decode(level+1, :len+1, null, level+1) parent_id 
from dual connect by level<=:len )
SELECT object_id
FROM objects
where level <= :n_objects
START WITH object_id = 1
CONNECT BY PRIOR parent_id = object_id
;
```